# React Router Dom Relative Path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, relative-path

I have an application published in a domain similar to this `"www.domain.com/app/client/store"`

When I developed it at the beginning, it was not contemplated that the domain be that way but something like `"www.domain.com"` the issue is that it is causing problems with the Router

when you access the initial route `"www.domain.com/app/client/store"` it does not find the path that is the login and jumps to management

I need that regardless of the url always find the initial path which `"/"`

My router currently looks like this

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/main" component={Main} />
        <Route exact path="/main/:id" component={Main} />
        <Route exact="/management" component={Management} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

The domain will be relative so it is not a good idea to put the absolute URL in the path

How can I make the route relative and not affect the initial page of the application?

The routes would be more or less like this

> "www.domain.com/app/client1/store5"
> "www.domain.com/app/client5/store1"
> "www.domain.com/app/client2/store3"

Thanks in advance for your help and feedback

Comment: You can provide a [`basename`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) prop to the router to match where the app is deployed on a server. Additionally, you may need to configure the server to serve all the nested "URL paths" from the base `index.html` file. You may also need to configure a home page in the package.json file. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to properly route, your path requires the public URL appended to every route.

```
const baseURL = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="${baseURL}/" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="${baseURL}/main" component={Main} />
        <Route exact path="${baseURL}/main/:id" component={Main} />
        <Route exact="${baseURL}/management" component={Management} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Something like that should work. There are also packages out there you could use in order to make life easier that would automatically append this, But this is a pretty simple approach.